# How can I run Presto on Google Cloud Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to run [Presto](https://prestodb.io/) on a Dataproc instance or on [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com) in general. How can I easily setup and install Presto, especially with Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/init-actions) with a Cloud Dataproc cluster to quickly install and configure Presto. Specifically, there is a [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions) repository with initialization actions. There is a [Presto initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/presto) which lets you quickly install and configure Presto.

If you want to use the Presto WebUI, once the cluster is online you can follow [these directions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces) to create an SSH tunnel and SOCKS proxy to the cluster. From there, you can access Presto (by default, unless you change it) on port `8080` on the master node.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official tutorial now [Use Presto with Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/presto-dataproc). Essentially, you can

1. Create a cluster with Presto init action:

`gcloud dataproc clusters create presto-cluster \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --num-workers=${WORKERS}  \
  --scopes=cloud-platform \
  --initialization-actions=gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/presto/presto.sh`

2. Create an SSH tunnel from your local machine to the master node:

`gcloud compute ssh presto-cluster-m \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --zone=${ZONE} \
    -- -D 1080 -N`

3. Connect to the Presto coordinator with Presto CLI through the SSH tunnel:

`./presto-cli \
    --server presto-cluster-m:8080 \
    --socks-proxy localhost:1080 \
    --catalog hive \
    --schema default`